# Why can't I my function to be called every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to call a function every few seconds as shown here:

HTML:

```
<div id="Result">Click here for the message.</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Result").click(function () {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $('post').each(function () {
                dater();
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
});

function dater() {
    $("#Result").text("hi");
}
```

The problem is that this is not being triggered; so, what am I missing, or doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Learn about `setInterval()`

Comment: Well to start, your fiddle is failing because jquery (`$ is not defined`) is not defined

Comment: In addition to what @Tom said, there are no elements in your fiddle that match the query `$('post')`, so `dater()` is never called.

Comment: You need to run `.setInterval()` instead of `.setTimeout()`

Comment: Thank you guys, I was posting on JSFiddle to show my code, but I'm testing on my own site, where JQuery is actually added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1**

You did not include jQuery in the JS Fiddle demo.

**Problem #2**

A `setTimeout` only executes once, unless it calls itself. Either do that or use `setInterval`, which executes every x milliseconds.

Also, there are no `<post>` elements in HTML, use a class instead. Also include it in the fiddle or it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Result").click(function () {
        var timeout = setInterval(function () {
            $('.post').each(dater);
        }, 3000);
    });
});

function dater() {
    $("#Result").text("hi");
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

**Note**

Both `setTimeout` and `setInterval` only start **after** the time set. If you want the function to be executed instantly as well, you could do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3a3c6kys/7/).

**Let's go further**

It might be a better choice to use `setTimeout`, as mentioned in other answers. Here is an example on how to do that:

```
var timeout;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Result").click(daterForEachPost);
});

function daterForEachPost() {
    $('.post').each(dater);
    // The function will call itself every 3000 ms
    timeout = setTimeout(daterForEachPost, 3000);
}

function dater() {
    $("#Result").text("hi");
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: I see, I didn't quite know what the 'post' was doing in this case, I took it from another question on SO about running a function every x seconds. This, however, works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `.setTimeout()` method will run only once. In order to run periodically (with the specified timeout interval), use `.setInterval()`.

Comment: Is SetInterval() not consistent in certain scenarios?

Comment: @Feign Imagine that every x milliseconds you request data from a server. If the connection is slow, the data might come back after a few of these calls have been made (Lookup asynchronous). In general, you would want to wait for the response before even trying to make another request. That's when `setTimeout` comes in handy, as you can trigger it only once the first call has ended.

Comment: @blex Hadn't even thought about that!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use setInterval() instead.
Here the information provided in w3schools.

"The setInterval() method will wait a specified number of milliseconds, and then execute a specified function, and it will continue to execute the function, once at every given time-interval."